# Request changing the logo from "Salesforce Stack Exchange" to "Salesforce.com Stack Exchange"

Tags: feature-request, design

Title is self explanatory. People can misunderstand Salesforce as "Sales Force."

Here is an example of a misunderstanding on SFSE: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129523/why-do-game-developers-develop-games-for-exclusive-contracts

Comment: Yes - that is true. Maybe you should write that Salesforce is an ERP System in Salesforce start page before you join this stack. The description confused me a little bit but I still thought it has something to do with sales questions.
Actually there is this text: `Salesforce Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for Salesforce administrators, implementation experts, developers and anybody in-between. It's 100% free, no registration required. `

Comment: I think that given the subject of this site what would we change it to? The site description is clear and I don't think using say the SFDC logo on the site would prevent that misunderstanding.

Comment: Does not seem necessary. This sort of misunderstanding is extremely rare, and could be alleviated by a minimal amount of research.

Comment: @DaveHumm, I have updated the question with the clarification. We can simply request to change the words in the logo from "Salesforce Stack Exchange" to "Salesforce.com Stack Exchange."

Comment: Suman, that would seem reasonable. Sorry misunderstood your original point.

Comment: Somewhat related (but not the same) : this discussion between force.com and salesforce for our name   http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/community-name-force-com-stack-exchange-vs-salesforce-stack-exchange

Answer (score 10):

I don't see the need. I believe most people refer to the platforms and services as Salesforce (related).

Our welcome [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) also explains this is about Salesforce, not 'Sales Force'. (We may want to add that this also covers all separate platforms and vertical clouds etc)

There are many many questions posted off-topic that are clearly off-topic for other reasons too. I'm not sure the small minority that confuses 'salesforce' with 'sales force' is worth the change or the risk or having people confuse 'salesforce' with 'salesforce.com'